# How to fix lapply with function with 3 variable

Tags: r, function, lapply

I'm writing the code to calculate a sum but my lapply have function which consist of 3 variable

I tried all apply function and reduce function `g` to 2 variables:

```
g<-function(x,y,z){
    res<-((x-((y*z)/sum(x))^2)/((y*z)/sum(x)))
    return(res)
}

lapply(A,FUN=g,apply(A,1,sum),apply(A,2,sum))
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `Map` instead of `lapply`. If you provide sample data and expected output, we might be able to verify and/or adapt.

Comment: `lapply` cannot do that. Use `mapply`